# Check that button is disabled in react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have a React component that generates a button whose content contains a `<span>` element like this one:

```
function Click(props) {
    return (
        <button disable={props.disable}>
            <span>Click me</span>
        </button>
    );
}
```

I want to test the logic of this component with the use of `react-testing-library` and `mocha` + `chai`.

The problem at which I stuck at the moment is that the `getByText("Click me")` selector returns the `<span>` DOM node, but for the tests, I need to check the `disable` attribute of the `<button>` node. What is the best practice for handling such test cases? I see a couple of solutions, but all of them sound a little bit off:

1. Use `data-test-id` for `<button>` element
2. Select one of the ancestors of the `<Click />` component and then select the button `within(...)` this scope
3. Click on the selected element with `fireEvent` and check that nothing has happened

Can you suggest a better approach?

Comment: Test that the disabled attribute of the button element is true?

Comment: Not OP's case, but for future visitors that came here looking to test `aria-disabled`, `.toBeDisabled()` won't work. The workaround is `.toHaveAttribute('aria-disabled', 'true')`. See [jest-dom #144](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom/issues/144#issuecomment-577235097).

Answer (score 213, accepted):

**Assert if button is disabled**

You can use the `toHaveAttribute` and `closest` to test it.

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

const { getByText } = render(Click);
expect(getByText(/Click me/i).closest('button')).toHaveAttribute('disabled');
```

or `toBeDisabled`

```
expect(getByText(/Click me/i).closest('button')).toBeDisabled();
```

---

**Assert if button is enabled**

To check if the button is enabled, use `not` as follows

```js
expect(getByText(/Click me/i).closest('button')).not.toBeDisabled();
```

Comment: Just a note: there must be a relatevily fresh version of the `jsdom` library to be able to use `closest(...)` function in your example (v 11.12.0 or higher)

Comment: Note that `toHaveAttribute` requires that https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom be installed.

Comment: For everyone using a different framework than jest, e.g. Jasmine, something like this should do the job: `expect(getByText(/Click me/i).closest('button').hasAttribute('disabled')).toBeTrue();`

Comment: While this answer works, personally I feel like its not aligned to the ethos of react-testing-library. I've provided an alternative answer below that, to me, is more in-tune with rtl  (not saying better or worse, just an alternative)

Comment: `TS2339: Property 'toBeDisabled' does not exist on type 'JestMatchers '.`

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa have you added `@testing-library/jest-dom`?

Comment: What I find funny is that even after the assertion of being disabled passes I can click the button and it triggers the callback... why?

Comment: if you want to check for not enabled elements then do this --------------------------



expect(getByText(/Click me/i).getAttribute("disabled")).toBeDefined()

Comment: I felt similarly to others about this approach being focused on implementation details, but it's noteworthy that in testing-library's own jest-dom implementation, `.toBeDisabled()` is [just checking the attribute](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom/blob/87ffd2a639dcf91fb59e38066136976e163df618/src/to-be-disabled.js#L44), and they recommend using this matcher for checking disabled state [in their own guide](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/example-intro/#quickstart).

Answer (score 39):

You can use `toBeDisabled()` from `@testing-library/jest-dom`, it is a custom jest matcher to test the state of the DOM:

https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom

Example:

```html
<button>Submit</button>
```

```js
expect(getByText(/submit/i)).toBeDisabled()
```

Answer (score 20):

For someone who is looking for the test in which the button is **not disabled**.

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

const { getByText } = render(Click);
expect(getByText(/Click me/i).getAttribute("disabled")).toBe(null)
```

Comment: instead of `.toBe(null)` use `.toBeNull()`.

Answer (score 14):

I would politely argue you are testing an implementation detail, which react-testing-library discourages.

> The more your tests resemble the way your software is used, the more confidence they can give you.

If a button is disabled, a user doesn't see a disabled prop, instead they see nothing happen. If a button is enabled, a user doesn't see the omission of a disabled prop, instead they see something happen.

I believe you should be testing for this instead:

```
const Button = (props) => (
  <button 
    type="submit" 
    onClick={props.onClick} 
    disabled={props.disabled}
  >
    Click me
  </button>
);

describe('Button', () => {
  it('will call onClick when enabled', () => {
    const onClick = jest.fn();
    render(<Button onClick={onClick} disabled={false} />);
    userEvent.click(getByRole('button', /click me/i));
    expect(onClick).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });

  it('will not call onClick when disabled', () => {
    const onClick = jest.fn();
    render(<Button onClick={onClick} disabled={true} />);
    userEvent.click(getByRole('button', /click me/i));
    expect(onClick).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
})
```

Comment: Good point! Altough I think that in the case of disabled button you can sacrifice the purity of concept and test "implementation details", especially when you test `disabled` attribute which is the part of the HTML specification with fixed behaviour.
Can you provide some example that will shows cons of testing `disabled` prop and pros of mocking `click` callback, just for my interest?

Comment: As @NikitaSivukhin stated, you are testing the HTML fixed behavior when you check if clicking a disabled button will trigger OnClick. While the user cannot see if a prop is disabled, they will see the visual effect of the disabled prop.

Comment: @LoganCundiff Of course. Basically "never say never" - there will always be exceptions to the "rules". I personally wouldn't check for the disabled attribute but there may be cases where it makes more sense to sacrifice the purity of the concept as Nikita said. Ultimately I don't know your codebase and you should do what fits within your team and projects

Comment: @Chris Yea I think it is good you brought up this point. It's worth asking these questions when considering how to implement a test instead of taking a one fit all approach. Good point.

Answer (score 6):

[toHaveAttribute](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tohaveattribute) is good option in using attribute.

```
<button data-testid="ok-button" type="submit" disabled>ok</button>

const button = getByTestId('ok-button')
//const button = getByRole('button');

expect(button).toHaveAttribute('disabled')
expect(button).toHaveAttribute('type', 'submit')
expect(button).not.toHaveAttribute('type', 'button')

expect(button).toHaveAttribute('type', expect.stringContaining('sub'))
expect(button).toHaveAttribute('type', expect.not.stringContaining('but'))
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You can test the disable prop of the button just by using `@testing-library/react` as follows.

example:

```
   import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

   const {getByText} = render(<Click/>)

   expect(getByText('Click me').closest('button').disabled).toBeTruthy()
```

Comment: I like this answer because it doesn't rely on another library. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to fix this would be to grab by the role and check the innerHTML like,

```
const { getByRole } = render(<Click />)
const button = getByRole('button')

// will make sure the 'Click me' text is in there somewhere
expect(button.innerHTML).toMatch(/Click me/))
```

This isn't the best solution for your specific case, but it's one to keep in your back pocket if you have to deal with a button component that's not an actual button, e.g.,

`<div role="button"><span>Click Me</span></div>`

Answer (score 1):

My solution, It seems to me that this case covers well what is necessary. Check that the button is disabled, so **toHaveBeenCalledTimes** must receive 0

```
 test('Will not call onClick when disabled', () => {
        const mockHandler = jest.fn()

        render(<Button title="Disabled account" disabled={true} onClick={mockHandler} />)
        const button = screen.getByText("Disabled account")
        fireEvent.click(button)

        expect(mockHandler).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0)
        expect(button).toHaveProperty('disabled', true)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Current answer:

```
expect(await screen.findByRole('button', { name: 'Click me' })).toBeEnabled();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **toBeDisabled()**

```
expect(getByText(/Click me/i).closest('button')).toBeDisabled();
```

Assert if button is **enabled**

To check if the button is enabled, use not as follows

```
expect(getByText(/Click me/i).closest('button')).not.toBeDisabled();
```